# javascript problem on php

Tags: javascript

Bellow is my php code .

```
    <div class="poller">

                <div class="poller_question" id="poller_question2">
                <p class="pollerTitle">Would you join a Community Action Committee?</p>
<p class="pollerOption"><input type="radio" value="6" name="vote[2]" id="pollerOption6">
<label for="pollerOption6" id="optionLabel6">Yes</label></p><p class="pollerOption">
<input type="radio" value="7" name="vote[2]" id="pollerOption7"><label for="pollerOption7" 
id="optionLabel7">Maybe</label></p><p class="pollerOption"><input type="radio" value="8" 
name="vote[2]" id="pollerOption8"><label for="pollerOption8" id="optionLabel8">No</label></p>           
                <a href="#" onclick="castMyVote(2,document.forms[0])"><imgsrc="images/vote_button.gif" border="0"></a>

                </div>
                <div class="poller_waitMessage" id="poller_waitMessage2">
                    Getting poll results. Please wait...
                </div>
                <div class="poller_results" id="poller_results2">
                <!-- This div will be filled from Ajax, so leave it empty --></div>
            </div>
```

Bellow is my javascript code

```
function castMyVote(pollId,formObj)
{   
    var elements = formObj.elements['vote[' + pollId + ']'];
    var optionId = false;
    for(var no=0;no<elements.length;no++){
        if(elements[no].checked)optionId = elements[no].value;
    }
    Poller_Set_Cookie('dhtmlgoodies_poller_' + pollId,'1',6000000);
    if(optionId){

        var ajaxIndex = ajaxObjects.length;
        ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex] = new sack();
        ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex].requestFile = serverSideFile + '?pollId=' + pollId + '&optionId=' + optionId;
        prepareForPollResults(pollId);
        ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex].onCompletion = function(){ showVoteResults(pollId,ajaxIndex); }; // Specify function that will be executed after file has been found
        ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex].runAJAX();       // Execute AJAX function    

    }   
}
```

form php i call a javascript method named "castMyVote" .The javascript is

```
var elements = formObj.elements['vote[' + pollId + ']'];
```

**create problem ? why ?How to solve it?var elements have no value**

Comment: Can you explain what and where exactly is your problem?

Comment: You should invest in some formatting.  Amongst other things, it makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("vote["+pollId+"]");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that your elements variable is not getting the correct value, **it is because the second parameter on your function CastMyVote requires a form but you do not have a form in your html**.
try this:

```
 <div class="poller">
<form method="post" action="#">
                <div class="poller_question" id="poller_question2">
                <p class="pollerTitle">Would you join a Community Action Committee?</p>
<p class="pollerOption"><input type="radio" value="6" name="vote[2]" id="pollerOption6">
<label for="pollerOption6" id="optionLabel6">Yes</label></p><p class="pollerOption">
<input type="radio" value="7" name="vote[2]" id="pollerOption7"><label for="pollerOption7" 
id="optionLabel7">Maybe</label></p><p class="pollerOption"><input type="radio" value="8" 
name="vote[2]" id="pollerOption8"><label for="pollerOption8" id="optionLabel8">No</label></p>           
                <a href="#" onclick="castMyVote(2,document.forms[0])"><imgsrc="images/vote_button.gif" border="0"></a>

                </div>
                <div class="poller_waitMessage" id="poller_waitMessage2">
                    Getting poll results. Please wait...
                </div>
                <div class="poller_results" id="poller_results2">
                <!-- This div will be filled from Ajax, so leave it empty --></div>
</form>
            </div>
```

I just put your divs and inputs inside the form.

Edit: your `<imgsrc="images/vote_button.gif" border="0">`. typo error?